# Invoking a macro with arguments in the body of \DeclareUnicodeCharacter.

Tags: unicode, babel

I would like to define the Unicode section character, U+00A7 to be equivalent to the \section macro. What I have now is:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{167}{\csname section\endcsname}
```

but this does not seem to work. Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{167}{\csname section\endcsname}
\begin{document}
§{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

that generates this error message:

```
! Extra \else.
\@sect ... {\csname the#1\endcsname }\fi #7}\else 
                                                  \def \@svsechd {#6{\hskip ...
l.6 §
      {Introduction}
```

I would not even know where to start to see what's going on.

Comment: Which TeX engine (pdftex, xetex,...) are you using?

Comment: Please post a minimal example document which recreates your error.

Comment: I use plain LaTeX, not even pdftex.

Comment: pdfTeX is used nowadays as the engine for LaTeX whether it's outputting PDF or DVI (although this is not often obvious from many GUI front-ends); in contrast to the newer Unicode-aware engines XeTeX and LuaTeX which can do things rather differently in this area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: It appears that `utf8x` breaks the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` command. A bug report would be in order, methinks. (Which I've [now done](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/d1ad206997ed4d76?hl=en) through semi-official channels.)

Here's how it should work: (my previous answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{A7}{\section}
\begin{document}
§{hello}
this is a fun idea
\end{document}
```

If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead you'll need a different approach: (never use inputenc in this case!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode"A7=\active
\let§\section
\begin{document}
§{hello}
this is a fun idea
\end{document}
```

I've always wanted to write a short package to unify the interfaces between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX here but haven't yet got around to it.

Comment: Works great, but without utf8x I cannot use babel.

Comment: Clever detective work, did I say?

Comment: @yossi Why does babel require utf8x for you?

Comment: Without it, I get an error message whenever I use Hebrew characters.